# How to I pass a list to cl-mustache?

Tags: common-lisp, mustache

I am trying to use [CL-MUSTACHE](https://github.com/kanru/cl-mustache). Rendering atomic variables works fine, following the examples in the [README](https://github.com/kanru/cl-mustache/blob/master/README.rst) file:

```
> (mustache:mustache-render-to-string "{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}" 
                                      '((:year . "2012")
                                        (:month . "07")
                                        (:day . "02")))
"2012-07-02"
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to pass a list to render a section multiple times. The [README](https://github.com/kanru/cl-mustache/blob/master/README.rst) file does not have an example, and the ways I have tried don't work. For example:

```
(mustache:mustache-render-to-string "{{#dates}}{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}
{{/dates}}" 
                                    '((:dates . (((:year . "2012")
                                                  (:month . "07")
                                                  (:day . "02"))
                                                 ((:year . "2013")
                                                  (:month . "08")
                                                  (:day . "03"))))))
"--
"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have it to check, but from the documentation, it seems that arrays are treated as CL arrays, so you can try this to see if it works:

```
(mustache:mustache-render-to-string "{{#dates}}{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}{{/dates}}" 
                                    '((:dates . #( ((:year . "2012")
                                                    (:month . "07")
                                                    (:day . "02"))
                                                   ((:year . "2013")
                                                    (:month . "08")
                                                    (:day . "03"))))))
```

(that is, an array of lists of parameters).